# booktabs's horizontal rules aren't displayed with cifa document class

Tags: tables, templates, rules, booktabs

There seems to be a problem between the [CIFA document class](http://controls.papercept.net/images/cifa/CIFA_Latex.zip)
and the *booktabs* package.
 When I compile the following code, the horizontal lines are not displayed:

```
\documentclass{cifa}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering 
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \toprule
        $Cell_{11}$ & $Cell_{12}$ \\
        \midrule
        $Cell_{21}$ & $Cell_{22}$ \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Bad table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If I use the *article* document class, the example compiles correctly.
Any workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thickness of the rules is defined by **booktabs** relative to the main document's font. However `cifa.cls` forgets to say `\normalsize` (which every class should do), so **booktabs** sets the thickness to a fraction of zero (because the font has not yet been chosen).

```
\documentclass{cifa}
\normalsize

<other packages>
```